# Silverlight read only cookies?

Tags: vb.net, cookies, silverlight-5.0, readonly

Is there a way to store data to be retrtived later, that can't be changed and stays between, reboots, reloads etc? In Silverlight with VB.NET, unlike cookies that can be changed with a simple extention or can be cleared..

Comment: Are you looking for [Isolated Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

Comment: All storage can be cleared by the user, and with Silverlight it's even convenient for the user - although IsolatedStorage is perhaps more overlooked than cookies.